# Node.js, access typescript static variable from different files

Tags: node.js, typescript, global-variables, static-variables

I have a situation like this in a node.js project:

test.ts

```
export class Test {
  private static test: string = 'hallo';

  public static initialize() {
    Test.test = 'changed';
  }

  public static showTest() {
    console.log(Test.test);
  }
}
```

At the begin I initalize Test..

app.ts

```
import { Test } from './test.ts'
...
Test.initialize();
Test.showTest();  // shows --> 'changed'
```

then I call a function of a class stored in another file
otherFile.ts

```
import { Test } from './test.ts'
...
someFunction() {
  Test.showTest();  // shows --> 'hallo'
}
```

Is there a way to make the showTest() function show 'changed' also on the second call without reinitializing Test?

Thank you!
Davide

Answer (score -2):

in this situation i prefer use  localStorage
because every time we import class , that reintilized